# Java AppEngine Backend Testing on local machine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, testing

I'm running appengine 1.6.1 using Google plugin for eclispse. How do i test my backend before i deploy it?

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine got you cover, just `debug as > Web Application` and it will run at http://localhost:8888/